# Java EE: Interface with a method that returns an instance of a helper class. Bad idea?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an interface that defines a method that returns an instance of a helper class and I was wondering if there's a better way of going about what I'm trying to do.

For example, say I have a Tag class:

```
public class Tag {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

You can assign Tags to other objects.

The assignment is represented by TagAssign:

```
public abstract class TagAssign {
    private Tag tag;

    public Tag getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(Tag tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

A new type of assignment will extend TagAssign and define what the Tag's being assigned to.

For example, a Tag assigned to a User would look like the following:

```
public class UserTag extends TagAssign {
    private long id;
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

An object that can have a tag assigned to it will implement the TagAssignable interface:

```
public interface TagAssignable {
    public TagAssignableHelper getTagAssignableHelper();
}
```

TagAssignable defines a method that returns an instance of TagAssignableHelper.

At the moment, TagAssignableHelper just defines a method that assigns the Tag to the TagAssignable, returning a TagAssign.

```
public interface TagAssignableHelper<A extends TagAssignable, T extends TagAssign> {
    public T assignTag(A assignable, Tag tag);
}
```

Here's what a User class that implements TagAssignable would look like:

```
public class User implements TagAssignable {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public UserTagAssignableHelper getTagAssignableHelper() {
        return new UserTagAssignableHelper();
    }
}
```

And UserTagAssignableHelper looks like:

```
public class UserTagAssignableHelper implements TagAssignableHelper<User, UserTag> {
    @Override
    public UserTag assignTag(User assignable, Tag tag) {
        UserTag userTag = new UserTag();
        userTag.setUser(assignable);
        userTag.setTag(tag);
        return userTag;
    }
}
```

The code in use:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TagAssignable> assignables = new ArrayList<>();
        assignables.add(new User());

        Tag tag = new Tag();

        List<TagAssign> assignments = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TagAssignable assignable : assignables) {
            TagAssign assignment = assignable.getTagAssignableHelper().assignTag(assignable, tag);
            assignments.add(assignment);
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want each type of TagAssignable to define how it's used inside the framework. When a developer marks a class as TagAssignable, they have to define how the TagAssign class is created, because at some point in the framework it's going to try and do just that.

I'm trying to avoid doing something like this:

```
    if(assignable instanceof User) {
        User user = (User) assignable;
        UserTag userTag = new UserTag();
        userTag.setTag(tag);
        userTag.setUser(user);
        return userTag;
    }
// followed by more ifs for each type of TagAssignable
```

I'm open to all feedback and suggestions.

Comment: can you add more info regarding exact usecases, what you want to achieve and how it can be used.

Comment: I've updated the "Code in use" section near the bottom of the post. Please let me know if that's alright.

Answer (score 1):

I think introducing the `TagAssign` class hierarchy complicates your design. What I would try to achieve is to change the `TagAssignable` interface to only have `Set<Tag> getTags()`, `add(Tag tag)` and `remove(Tag tag)` tags. If you want to achieve immutability of objects with tags, you could change the interface to have `with(Tag tag)` and `without(Tag tag)` methods that return mutated instances. This would remove the need for separate assignment classes and their corresponding helpers.

Comment: Hmm you might be right. At the moment TagAssign is a JPA entity that has a SQL table associated with it.

Comment: I do know you can have lazy collections in Hibernate so that might actually work.